# Heroku automatic deploys and TravisCI: how it works?

Tags: heroku, github, travis-ci

So my manager asked me to enable automatic deploys(Heroku feature) from DEV branch, to easily control which branch to deploy from GitHub using the Heroku web GUI. But We also have TravisCI which we use for code analyze with SonaQube and test running and **deployment to Heroku**

My question is: how to configure *automatic deploy* feature from Heroku, to select which branch to deploy, but be able running CI from Travis before that?

Travis file example:

```
sudo: false
language: node_js
node_js:
- '6'
cache:
  directories:
  - node_modules
install:
- npm install
script:
- npm run test
- npm run build
after_success:
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: 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
  app: xxxxxxxxx
  strategy: api
  on:
    repo: FortumSELisa/reactjs-spa-app
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is that covered in this doc https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#automatic-deploys

Comment: Yeah! Understood. I removed "deploy" from .travis.yml and configured auto deploy from heroku. Also, checked the "Wait for CI to finish". Works good!